# Where to place a properties file so the java command will see it in the classpath

Tags: java

We have a jar which needs to read a properties file. The properties file needs to edited without rebuilding the application, therefore it is excluded from the build.

In order for the application to see the properties file, it is placed it a folder which is on the java classpath. The format of the Windows command line used to run the application is as follows:

```
java -cp application.jar;.\lib_folder\*; com.company.Start
```

Java correctly picks up all the jar files in the `lib_folder`. The properties file is placed in the same folder, but the application cannot see it and is throwing a FileNotFoundException. Are we doing anything obviously wrong?

Thanks very much

Comment: Could you please show the code which reads the properties-file?

Comment: It is a Spring app. In the xml, I declare a bean of type PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer, and then simply declare the properties file in the locations tab. If I include the properties file in the jar, this works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class resolution happens starting from the path given in cp. If you provide .\lib_folder in the classpath without the star, and the properties file is inside this folder, then it will be picked up. Currently the properties file itself is in the classpath.

Comment: Without the '\*' following the name of the folder defined in the classpath, none of the jars are picked up - I just tried it. So that does not appear to ne the solution.

Comment: well put the properties file in a different folder and add that in addition to your existing entries. Don't use a star in the new folder path.

Comment: I understand. Thanks for your answer, this works. I moved the properties file outside of the lib_folder, and into the same folder as the application is running in. Then I added '.' to the classpath. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> it is placed it a folder which is on the java classpath

Your class path only contains JARs, the notation `.\lib_folder\*` means every jar from a folder, but not the folder itself.

> The properties file is placed in the same folder, but the application cannot see it

The folder itself need to be added, however I suspect you shouldn't be adding files to the "lib" directory and you should be using a different directory like "config"

> and is throwing a FileNotFoundException.

When you try to obtain a Resource you get `null` not this exception.  Try the following

```
InputStream is = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("resource.properties");
```

This returns `null` if the file is not found.

> Are we doing anything obviously wrong?

FileInputStream looks for a direct file, it doesn't use the classpath.

Comment: ok, thanks. How do I specify on the command line that I want the properties file to be picked up, not just the jars?

Comment: @user1052610 you specify the directory without a `*` to say you also want the files in that directory.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using ResourceBundle to read the property files, then just add the top level project containing the .properties files to the classpath.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. The properties file needs to be outside of any jar.

Comment: Lets assume your property file is called MYProps.properties, in java project called PropertyHolder, and somewhere in your jar you load them as such: ResourceBundle rb = ResourceBundle.getBundle("MyProps"); In this case your classpath has to be configured to be something like C:\somewhere\somewhere\PropertyHolder\ in order for that to work.